# How do I format the rows and the month names in Angular UI date picker?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui

I cant seem to find it in the documentation, and my last resort is to override the template. Currently, I am using the view mode `months`, and its showing the whole month name. I just want the short version, for example, Jan, Feb, Mar.

Also, the default grid for months seems to be 4x3, but I want it to be 3x4. Does anyone know how to do this?

```
   <div ng-model="vm.currentDate"
           datepicker-popup="MMM yyyy"
           is-open="vm.pickerOpen"
           min-date="vm.minDate"
           max-date="vm.maxDate"
           show-button-bar="false"
           datepicker-options="{minMode:'month', maxMode:'month', class:'green-date-picker' }"
           datepicker-mode="'month'"
           ng-click="vm.openDatePicker($event)">
```

Answer (score 1):

From this [link](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/)

```
format-month="MMM"
```

Also, the documentation is in the upper link in this sentence...

> Everything is formatted using the **date filter** and thus is also localized.

Link is in bold above, but blue on page (as usual).